# deleteRecord doesn't update ArrayController when Model is filtered

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using a simple `Ember.ArrayController` in an application with `ember-data` (latest), `ember rc6` and a stock REST controller.

I have delete actions next to each item in the list rendered by the array controller. When an item is deleted, the proper REST API call is made and it's removed from the database properly. Server responds with the correct `204` response.

Here is my router setup, notice the find filter being applied

```
App.CategoriesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController : function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);

        controller.set("content", App.Category.find({
            "parent": null,
        }));
    }
});
```

If I remove the find filter and load all categories, everything works fine (item is automatically removed from the list immediately after commit). However, when I add the filter to only display categories that don't have a parent, the list is not updated when an item is deleted. If I transition to another section and come back, the list is reloaded and the category is gone.

Here is `deleteCategory` method in the `ArrayController`:

```
deleteCategory: function(category) {
    var transaction = this.get("store").transaction();

    transaction.add(category);
    category.deleteRecord();
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Is this an `ember-data` or `emberjs` bug? If not, what am I doing wrong here? If it's a bug, is there a way to force-reload the ArrayController contents after I delete an item? Alternatively, can I remove the category from the ArrayController manually?

UPDATE 1:

I managed to force-update the array controller's contents by setting its content:

```
category.one("didDelete", this, function() {
    this.set("content", App.Category.find({
        parent: parent_category
    }));
});
```

UPDATE 2:

Here is how I am displaying the list of items in the template:

```
{{#each category in controller.content }}
<tr>
    <td><a {{ action "detailCategory" category }}>{{ category.name }}</a></td>
    <td><a {{ action "deleteCategory" category }}>Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Two notes: I tested this with other kinds of filters, and it fails if any filter is applied to the model query. It only works with no filters, otherwise the list is not updated. I also found a way to force-reload the ArrayController's query by setting its content after the deletion is complete. This will do for now, but it's a nasty hack.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I finally tracked this issue down to checkboxes I had next to each item in the list. Every checkbox was bound to an attribute on the related object, and it was triggering erroneous events when loading the list, causing this issue. I ended up removing the checkboxes and events related to them to fix the problem. If you need more details I'll dig further and let you know.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you tracked the issue? I'm having similar problems (view stays after deleteRecord), but I have no idea on how to track the issue.

Comment: @Nico I was guessing that this had something to do with data bindings, so I started progressively removing every binding I could think of. Since this was a list view, there wasn't much to test with. When checkboxes were removed, everything started working properly. For the record, we moved away from Ember.js after having many of these issues. It's an unstable and poorly designed framework. It cannot even be compared to Angular.js in terms of stability and usability.

Comment: @TaylanPince I'm beginning to think my lazy choise for ember was a mistake, too. It seemed like it had a lot more out of the box but... You need to know every in and out to be even working with this beast. Every answer on stackoverflow is already dated. Even their own documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer the way to do things in Ember Data. One would not use transactions any longer, as can be seen in the transition doc: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: I've deleted my question, and I cannot accept yours because I'm not the one who asked :) you should bug Taylan Pince ...

Comment: Yeah, every comment "bugs" the OP, if I understand stack overflow correctly... I'm not sure what question you're referring to, sorry, but all good :) Stack overflow is annoying if you want to clear out old stuff, I've found. "answered" means "answered and have that answer accepted".